# BUILD ERROR - Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, angular7

I have created a angular library named ng-common-lib. Created a component in side library which reads contents from a json file.

jsonFile.json

```
{
    "name" : "Sunil"
}
```

Below code to read json file in my component.

```
import * as jsonFile from '../../../assets/jsonFile.json';
.....
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(jsonFile); 
}
```

Added below two lines to **tsconfig.json** to read data from json file.

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

Then I have ran **ng build ng-common-lib** command to generate build, but it got failed with below error.

```
users-iMac:ng-ui-library user$ ng build ui-components
Building Angular Package
Building entry point '@ui/components'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015

BUILD ERROR
Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.transform (/Users/vasu/Desktop/Sunil/Practice/ng-ui-lib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-json/dist/rollup-plugin-json.cjs.js:18:20)
    at /Users/vasu/Desktop/Sunil/Practice/ng-ui-lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:20962:25
    at <anonymous>
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: whats your json file look like?

Comment: @Daniel, I have added json file as well.

Comment: @SunilKumarSahu is this resolved if yes pleae update

Comment: @RahulSharma Where do I need to update? I couldn't find any option to mark it resolved. Could you please help.

Comment: @SunilKumarSahu how did you resolve it ? facing the same issue, is there a bug in angular 7

Comment: After digging around I realise to solve it by setting "annotateForClosureCompiler": false in angularCompilerOptions

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm setting `annotateForClosureCompiler` to `false` in `tsconfig.lib.json` fixed this for me.

Comment: Thank you for this. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the json file content using http
So first you need to create a service to fetch the json content

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class JsonSettingService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

   public getJsonData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/jsonFile.json");
  }
}
```

Then inject your service into your component

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private jsonSettingService : JsonSettingService  
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(){
       this.jsonSettingService.getJsonData().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
   }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any help.